# VSO/VSTS: Error when using Publish Build Artifacts on the host agent

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-devops

When using the Publish Build Artifacts task, the following error gets thrown in the build (just after "Get sources"):

> The definition for the task does not have a handler that matches any
>   supported by this agent. Supported handlers: AzurePowerShell,
>   AzurePowerShellHandler, PowerShell, PowerShellHandler, PowerShellExe,
>   PowerShellExeHandler, Process, ProcessHandler

I am using the VSTS (formally known as VSO) Host Agent.

[image: Publish Build Artifacts]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue too. Checked the source code for "[Publish build artifacts](https://github.com/Microsoft/vso-agent-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/PublishBuildArtifacts)", this issue seems to be caused by the PowerShell script is missing. I have help you submit a feedback to MS, you can track the status [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2059436).

For now, you can use "Copy and Publish Build Artifacts" task to publish your artifacts.
[image]