# The item MY_ARTIFACT_NAME in container XXX could not be found

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ms-release-management, azure-web-app-service

When attempting to configure MS Release Manager based on the tutorial [Deploying your applications to Azure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Release/getting-started/deploy-to-azure#website), modified per [Error when using Publish Build Artifacts on the host agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33917308/vso-vsts-error-when-using-publish-build-artifacts-on-the-host-agent), I receive the following exception:

> The item `MY_ARTIFACT_NAME` in container 56811 could not be found.

which results in the release being rejected.

I have added the `system.debug` variable and set it to **true**,(see [Publish build artifacts - I'm having problems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/steps/build/publish-build-artifacts#Q_AQ_Imhavingproblems_HowcanItroubleshootthem)) but no additional information is provided.

My Visual Studio Build completes successfully and is configured like so:

**MSBuild Arguments:**

`/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true
/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.stagingDirectory)"`

**Platform:** `$(BuildPlatform)`

**Configuration:** `$(BuildConfiguration)`

Copy and Publish Build Artifacts

**Contents:** `*.*`

**Artifact Name:** `MY_ARTIFACT_NAME`

**Artifact Type:** `Server`

My Azure Web App Deployment is configured like so:

**Web Deploy Package:** `$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\**\*.zip`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Copy and Publish Build Artifacts" task isn't copying anything to artifact folder with your configuration, you need to configure it as following:

```
Copy Root: $(build.stagingDirectory)
Contents: **\*.zip
Artifact Name: MY_ARTIFACT_NAME
Artifact Type: Server
```

And in your release definition, "$(Agent.BuildDirectory)" does not work either. You need to use the $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\*.zip by default.

Comment: didn't work. 
##[error]Downloading artifacts failed: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.FileContainer.ContainerItemNotFoundException: The item drop in container 542726 could not be found.