# TFS: Setup CI deployments for DEV server

Tags: deployment, tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, continuous-deployment

**Goal**

Publish successful web app CI builds to IIS dev server.

**Current Setup**

The associated *build definition* first *copies* the `\bin` folder content to the `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory`, then *publishes* the artifacts of the same path. The name value is `drop` and the type is `Server`.

The *release definition* contains only a `Windows Machine File Copy` step. It's `Source` property points to the aforementioned drop folder, and its destination is a UNC address.

Its `Artifacts` tab is linked to the build definition and `Continuous Deployment` is enabled for the same source.

**Symptom**

Deployment status is `Rejected`. The error returned is `The item drop in container 10039 could not be found.` See log below:

`2016-12-02T01:46:47.1273383Z Cleaning artifacts directory: C:\agent_work\9ee18c2ab…
2016-12-02T01:46:47.1612721Z Cleaned artifacts directory: C:\agent_work\9ee18c2ab
2016-12-02T01:46:47.1692742Z Number of linked artifacts to download: 1 
2016-12-02T01:46:47.1722775Z Starting artifacts download...
2016-12-02T01:46:47.2203037Z Downloading linked artifact: VehicleTracking.DevCI...
2016-12-02T01:46:47.2222969Z Downloading artifact of type: Build
2016-12-02T01:46:47.2252925Z Created artifact folder C:\agent_work\9ee18c2ab\VehicleTracking.DevCI
2016-12-02T01:46:47.2712805Z Preparing to get the list of available artifacts from build.
2016-12-02T01:46:47.4233327Z Preparing to download artifact: drop
2016-12-02T01:46:47.4593025Z Artifact Type: ServerDrop
2016-12-02T01:46:47.4613413Z The artifact is of older version: False
2016-12-02T01:46:47.8273312Z Caching items under 'drop' in the file container...
2016-12-02T01:46:48.3123751Z 0 placed file(s): 0 downloaded, 0 empty and new, 0 preserved.
2016-12-02T01:46:48.3273435Z An error occurred during download: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.FileContainer.ContainerItemNotFoundException: The item drop in container 10039 could not be found.`

**Questions**

Why is the drop not found? Is there something wrong with the build or something wrong with the release?

Comment: Can you see the published artifacts from build?

Answer (score 1):

Either the drop-folder from your build (Web App CI build) is not available anymore or your IIS server can't access the drop folder(lack of permission).

You could verify ( after queuing a new build) that if the drop-folder is there  and that there are files in the drop-folder. You could verify this by opening the build and going to the artifacts section and exploring the drop-folder, as show over [here](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2015/06/30/manage-artifacts-with-tfs-build-vnext/).

You could also double check if you are using the right arguments, the similar issue for your reference:  [The item MY_ARTIFACT_NAME in container XXX could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34165912/the-item-my-artifact-name-in-container-xxx-could-not-be-found)