# TFS 2015 Artifacts always empty upon build

Tags: tfs-2015, release-management

I have created build definition which runs successfully. Now I want to create a release definition on the successful build, for which it is asking for artifacts.

When I tried browsing "Drop" folder, I found it empty.

Below are the images from Copy Files step and Publish build artifacts step.

I also tried instructions from [The item MY_ARTIFACT_NAME in container XXX could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34165912/the-item-my-artifact-name-in-container-xxx-could-not-be-found) 
But no luck. Please help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you should use `$(build.sourcesdirectory)` (or a path relative to) as the source folder if you want to copy files which are not checked in.

Also, from the documentation of the [Copy Files step](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-files)

> The pattern is used to match only file paths, not folder paths. So you should specify patterns such as `**\bin\**` instead of of `**\bin`.

Try changing the contents pattern to `**\bin\**` and see if that helps.

Comment: You Saved My Life, Justin. Humanity and divinity still exits in the form of people like you in the world.